# Regularization using complexity penalty

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian, regularization

I am currently reading murphy and i came across regularization
The issue i am facing is building intuitive sense behind the complexity penalty they have used [image]

how can having log on my prior belief will penalize the model from overfitting ??

Answer (score 2):

The left term is sum of fitting error over all the data points.

The right term is a cost of adding/increasing a parameter value.

Since the same cost can be achieved by large error and small number of parameters and vice versa , this implicitly defines a trade off:

A parameter will only be large if it has a strong enough change on the total error.

$\lambda$ is the trade off factor, error per unit increase in complexity

Overfitting is using too many parameters for individual data points. Regularisation reduces that, because it introduces a cost of making the model more complex: unless the model change makes a sufficient reduction in the total error (eg reducing error on lots of points, not just 1),then the lower complexity solution will be chosen

Answer (score 1):

The argument in the provided text snippet is that a prior over your parameter reduces model complexity. A *complex* model is one, in which many if not all parameters are non-zero; in contrast, a sparse model has many zero parameters. When estimating parameters, we seek a parameter vector that minimizes the loss function. By adding $-log(p(\theta))$ to the loss function, we add a force that pulls the parameter vector towards points with higher likelihood of the prior when finding a solution (because higher log-likelihood translates to a smaller penalty). In order to force the model to a sparse solution, the prior need to be centered at zero, such that parameter estimates are actually pulled towards zero and thus are basically dropped from the model. In a lot of situations, simple models make (on average) more robust prediction